# How to show related content using like in mysql?

Tags: mysql, tags

I currently have a table for products with it's own set of tags and a table for news with it's own set of tags. I wanted to add related news to the products page so I was thinking of using  **like** but since the column tags in the products page is something like
(Products) tags- manutd, man utd, football
(news) tags - manutd, blah, bruha   [**this one is related**]
(news) tags - man, utd, bruha   [**this one is not related**]
I wanted to use a query to show all news containing any of the tags(from products) seperated by commas using mysql. How should I go about constructing such a query?
 If there is a better way of doing this a little explanation would be helpful too. Thanks

Comment: Is the news tag "manutd" supposed to refer to product tags "manutd", "man", and "utd"?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the product tags at hand or do you want to join the two tables based on their tag similarity? In the first case, I would try something like this:

```
select ...
  from News n
 where n.tags REGEXP 'manutd|man utd|football'
```

Note that I used the product tag string you provided above, replaced the commas by `|` and removed the whitespace to the left and right of the commas.